# Java: String split acting weird

Tags: java, string, split

```
public String getPriceString() {
    String priceString = "45.0";
    String[] priceStringArray = priceString.split(".");
    return priceStringArray.length + "";
}
```

Why does this give me a 0, zero? Shouldn't this be 2?

Comment: Thanks everyone! I found it out just before refreshing that it's a regex code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument to [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is a regular expression, and dot has a special meaning in regular expressions (it matches any character).

Try `priceString.split("[.]");`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `.` like that

```
String[] priceStringArray = priceString.split("\\.");
```

`split` takes regular expression as a parameter and `.` means any character.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Answer (score 0):

escape `.` with backslash like `\\.`. `.` is a regex **metacharacter** for anything. you will have to escape it with `\\.` in order to make it treat as a **normal character**

```
        String priceString = "45.0";
        String[] priceStringArray = priceString.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.split` takes a regular expression pattern. You're passing in `.` which means you want to split on *any character*.

You *could* use `"\\."` as the pattern to split on - but personally I'd use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) instead:

```
private static final Splitter DOT_SPLITTER = Splitter.on('.');
...
```

(If you're not already using Guava, you'll find *loads* of goodies in there.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `.` as `\\.` because `.` has special meaning in regex.

```
String priceString = "45.0";
String[] priceStringArray = priceString.split("\\.");
return priceStringArray.length + "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String[] priceStringArray = priceString.split("\\.");`
You will have to use escape sequence.